# Need Guidance in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, selenium-webdriver, testng

i have learned basics of Selenium webdriver like, Data driven framework,Keyword driven ,page factory and basic commands etc. My doubt is how to start the write the test scripts, i don't have any clear idea. anybody help me.. suggest me some ways. give me some example projects or ideas.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not a real question.

Comment: @Ant's   i asked any sample projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with (depending how you want to do it) building the PageObject pattern with Google, start preforming searches in Google etc.

Comment: can you give any full example for a project/websites

Comment: Here is a good example: http://assertselenium.com/automation-design-practices/page-object-pattern/